# Android: understanding the function  remapCoordinateSystem 

Tags: android, screen-orientation, device-orientation, rotational-matrices

I have been trying to understand these 2 lines of code

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(RTmp, I, grav, mag); 
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(RTmp, SensorManager.AXIS_X,SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, Rot);
```

I read [the documentation of `remapCoordinateSystem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#remapCoordinateSystem%28float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float%5B%5D%29), however I am lost.

Can anyone explain to me what exactly `getRotationMatrix` and `remapCoordinateSystem` do? Specially the `SensorManager.AXIS_X`, `SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z`?

Comment: This might help: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html

Answer (score 3):

I believe `getRotationMatrix()` returns a rotation matrix that converts **device coordinate** to **world coordinate**, as mentioned in [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29), not "world" to "device".

> Computes the inclination matrix I as well as the rotation matrix R
>   transforming a vector from the **device coordinate system** to the
>   **world's coordinate system** which is defined as a direct orthonormal basis, where

Answer (score 1):

I think the function of `getRotationMatrix()` was clearly explained by @Noname. I am trying to answer your second and third questions considering `remapCoordinateSystem()` and `SensorManager.AXIS_X`, `SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z`. 

 What `remapCoordinateSystem()` does is actually changing the CoordinateSystem, setting the new X, Y, Z-AXIS where `SensorManager.AXIS_X`, `SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z` are the coordinate system of your phone. From your code, I believe you are doing augmented reality in portrait orientation. That's why you set  Y-axis to  `SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z` FYI. If you want to do the same thing in landscape orientation, you will set the coordinate system as follow:

```
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(RTmp, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, Rot);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Asking such a question totally out of context is generally hard to answer. Also you should get familiar with formatting (e.g: 4 spaces indicates code):

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(RTmp, I, grav, mag);
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(RTmp, SensorManager.AXIS_X,SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, Rot);
```

However:

I would say that you are on the right track using the documentation. As you see getRotationMatrix pulls the current rotation matrix needed to transform the "world coordinate system" to the current device coordinate system.
Additionally remapcoordinateSystem transforms the given coordinate System accordingly to the given rotation Matrix.
But as stated above - out of context it is hard to tell you WHY somebody is doing this.